# WinJS share target with write access to file

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

My application acts as a share target for any file.
I have read access to the instances of `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` objects, through:

```
    if (shareOperation.data.contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.storageItems)) {
        shareOperation.data.getStorageItemsAsync().then(function (storageItems) {
            for (var i = 0; i < storageItems.size; i++) {
                var storageFile = storageItems.getAt(i);
                // storageFile is of type Windows.Storage.StorageFile
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I want to write the file, I get an exception (0x80071779) that the file is read-only.

Is there any way to gain write access (including delete permission) to a file that has been received through the share contract?

I searched the net, but was not able to find any answer or even example that included write.

Comment: Can your app be a target from a file picker? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465192.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look if that could be an alternative.

Comment: How did this end up for you?

Comment: Sorry, didn't follow that path, but at the moment I am rewriting my app completely and maybe I will try again to add such a feature.